# How to change height or width of pdf in react (npm react-pdf)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-pdf

Change the loaded pdf layout (height and width) in react-pdf.

This includes :

1. Load pdf in reactjs
2. Modify height and width of pdf.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First if you want to load a pdf in reactjs, you can refer this article https://levelup.gitconnected.com/displaying-pdf-in-react-app-6e9d1fffa1a9

And you can also clone https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf

After that, add some css to position it to center and define your own height and width of the document

```
.react-pdf__Page__canvas {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Document and Page components also have 'className' prop names.
you can set a className to target that Page (but will need to use the above mentioned class or the 'canvas' element within it). Because style tags have been applied to it, you will need to override with !important as done in the answer above

Comment: I have a better solution:
`<Page pageNumber={1} height={document.getElementsByClassName('PdfDiv')[0]?.clientHeight*0.8 ?? 150}`
So you have a percentual height of the parent div.